# how to create java files and XML in android folder of flutter

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter, native

i want to write some native code for printer purpose in flutter so i wrote some code for connection between the flutter and android but i am facing issue when i am trying create another java class xml in android folder. Explain me how to create new java class xml file in android folder of flutter.

flutter:

```
 import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
class ExamplemyApp  extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample Shared App Handler',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SampleAppPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SampleAppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SampleAppPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleAppPageState createState() => _SampleAppPageState();
}

class _SampleAppPageState extends State<SampleAppPage> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('app.channel.shared.data');
  String dataShared = "Restos printer working";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text(dataShared)));
  }

  getSharedText() async {
    var sharedData = await platform.invokeMethod("getSharedText");
    if (sharedData != null) {
      setState(() {
        dataShared = sharedData;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

ANDROID:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.ActivityLifecycleListener;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private String sharedText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "app.channel.shared.data").setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                        if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
                            result.success(sharedText);
                            sharedText = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    }
}
```

Now i want move from mainactivity.java to another activtiy for printing

if i try to write new jav and i am getting this error;

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'build\app.dill.track.dill' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

, errno = 3)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:368:9)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#5      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:486:5)
#6      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:516:7)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#9      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: The pipe is being closed.
, errno = 232), port = 0
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```